# Detect Phone Browsers to show "Call" even thought resolution is high

Tags: android, css, iphone, mobile, tel

I am using the fluid css design with three different style sheets to change depending on screen resolution.
I have "Call" and "Directions" buttons built into 800px width or smaller, because most modern phones are coming out with resolution widths in that range.
My dilemma is if someone has an older computer with, say 800x600, they will see these buttons. I don't want to get rid of my fluid css design, but I'd like to hide the two div's I have on non-phone devices, even tablets.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PHP, try "Mobile Detect"
https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Or, if you want another language, take a look at these solutions:
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/